# Why can't I change my private data of an instance in copy constructor if it's const?

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list, constants, copy-constructor

So I am making a linked list, in which I have successfully implemented the insert method. But next I have to copy an OrderedLinkedList instances data over to a new empty instance. The problem is when I try to access the "head" pointer of the empty LinkedList, it says I can't access the head because it is constant. Below is the full description of the error.

Full Error

```
>------ Build started: Project: betterLinkedList, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  assign3_driver.cpp
1>c:\users\w01104311\downloads\assign3 (1)\assign3\orderedlinkedlist.h(67): error C3490: 'head' cannot be modified because it is being accessed through a const object
1>          c:\users\w01104311\downloads\assign3 (1)\assign3\orderedlinkedlist.h(64) : while compiling class template member function 'void OrderedLinkedList<Type>::copy(const OrderedLinkedList<Type> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=MemberDO
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\w01104311\downloads\assign3 (1)\assign3\orderedlinkedlist.h(60) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void OrderedLinkedList<Type>::copy(const OrderedLinkedList<Type> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=MemberDO
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\w01104311\downloads\assign3 (1)\assign3\orderedlinkedlist.h(58) : while compiling class template member function 'OrderedLinkedList<Type>::OrderedLinkedList(const OrderedLinkedList<Type> &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=MemberDO
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\w01104311\downloads\assign3 (1)\assign3\assign3_driver.cpp(95) : see reference to function template instantiation 'OrderedLinkedList<Type>::OrderedLinkedList(const OrderedLinkedList<Type> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=MemberDO
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\w01104311\downloads\assign3 (1)\assign3\assign3_driver.cpp(42) : see reference to class template instantiation 'OrderedLinkedList<Type>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=MemberDO
1>          ]
1>c:\users\w01104311\downloads\assign3 (1)\assign3\orderedlinkedlist.h(74): error C2664: 'Node<Type>::Node(const Node<Type> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'MemberDO' to 'const Node<Type> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=MemberDO
1>          ]
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'MemberDO' to 'const Node<Type>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=MemberDO
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>c:\users\w01104311\downloads\assign3 (1)\assign3\orderedlinkedlist.h(79): error C2664: 'Node<Type>::Node(const Node<Type> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'MemberDO' to 'const Node<Type> &'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=MemberDO
1>          ]
1>          Reason: cannot convert from 'MemberDO' to 'const Node<Type>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Type=MemberDO
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>  Generating Code...
1>  Compiling...
1>  MemberDO.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

So how do I change this new LinkedLists data(example change the head pointer and tail pointers)?? Here is my code:

```
   #ifndef ORDEREDLINKEDLIST_H
    #define ORDEREDLINKEDLIST_H

    template <class Type>
    struct Node
    {
        Node<Type>();
        Type info;
        Node*next;

    };



    template <class Type>
    class OrderedLinkedList
    {
    public:
        OrderedLinkedList();
        OrderedLinkedList(const OrderedLinkedList& other);
        ~OrderedLinkedList();

        OrderedLinkedList<Type>& operator=(const OrderedLinkedList<Type>& other);


        int insert(const Type&);
        Type* find(int) const;
        Type* get(int) const;
        int remove(int);
            void clear();
            int size() const;
        void print() const;
    private:
        void copy(const OrderedLinkedList<Type>& other);
        int length;
        Node<Type>* head;
        Node<Type>* tail;
    };


    template <class Type>
    Node<Type>::Node(){
        next = NULL;

    }

    template <class Type>
    OrderedLinkedList<Type>::OrderedLinkedList()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        length = 0;

    }

    template <class Type>
    OrderedLinkedList<Type>::OrderedLinkedList(const OrderedLinkedList& other)
    {

        copy(other);
    }

    template <class Type>
    void OrderedLinkedList<Type>::copy(const OrderedLinkedList& other){

        length = other.length;
    if( other.head = NULL){

        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        return;

    }
    head = new Node<Type>(other.head->info);
    Node<Type>* current = other.head->next;
    Node<Type>* node = head;
    while(current!=NULL){

        node->next = new Node<Type>(current->info);
        if(current->next = NULL){
        tail = current;
        }
        current = current->next;
        node = node->next;
    }


    }

    template <class Type>
    OrderedLinkedList<Type>& OrderedLinkedList<Type>::operator=(const OrderedLinkedList& other)
    {
    return *this;
    }

    template <class Type>
    int OrderedLinkedList<Type>::insert(const Type& item)
    {
        Node<Type>* newNode = new Node<Type>();
        Node<Type>* tmp = new Node<Type>();
        Node<Type>* prev = new Node<Type>(); 
        newNode->info = item;
        bool firstNode = true;


        if(head !=NULL){
            tmp = head;

            while(tmp != NULL && newNode->info.getKey()>tmp->info.getKey()){//put keys in order
                if(firstNode){
                    firstNode = false;
                }
                prev = tmp;//keeps track of previous node
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }


            if(firstNode){//if first item in the list
                head = newNode;
            }else{prev->next = newNode;}

            if(tmp == NULL){//if last item in the list
                newNode->next = NULL;
            }else{newNode->next = tmp;}

        }else{
        head = newNode;
        }


        while(newNode->next != NULL){

            newNode = newNode->next;

        }
        tail = newNode;

        length++;





        return newNode->info.getKey();
    }

    template<class Type>
    Type* OrderedLinkedList<Type>::get(int dest) const
    {
        if(dest>length-1 || dest < 0){
            return NULL;
        }
        Node<Type>*curr = new Node<Type>;
        int currCount = 0;
        curr = head;

        while(currCount < dest){

            curr = curr->next;
            currCount++;

        }

        return &(curr->info);//did not delete curr
    }

    template <class Type>
    Type* OrderedLinkedList<Type>::find(int key) const
    {
        if(key < 0){return NULL;}//checks if negative, if it is return NULL
        Node<Type>*curr = new Node<Type>;
        int currCount = 0;
        curr = head;

        while(curr != NULL && curr->info.getKey() != key){

            curr = curr->next;
            currCount++;

        }
        if(curr==NULL){

        return NULL;

        }

            return &(curr->info);
    }

    template <class Type>
    int OrderedLinkedList<Type>::remove(int key)
    {
    return 0;
    }

    template <class Type>
    void OrderedLinkedList<Type>::clear()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
        length = 0;
    }


    template <class Type>
    int OrderedLinkedList<Type>::size() const
    {
        return length;
    }

    template <class Type>
    void OrderedLinkedList<Type>::print() const
    {
    }
    #endif
```

Here is the call from the driver source file

```
OrderedLinkedList<MemberDO> copy(memberList);
```

There is more code that holds the data but I don't think its needed in this situation. I could be wrong though so let me know if you need more code. Thanks in advance for the help!!

Comment: *Because* it's `const`.

Comment: "change" "when it's const" Think about it.

Comment: As an aside, note that these lines are assignment not comparisons: `if( other.head = NULL){`, and `if(current->next = NULL){`

Comment: _"let me know if you need more code."_ Always, the first time, without being prompted, provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise all you're doing is forcing me to type out this URL again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Node` class template has no constructor that takes a `Type` (its template parameter), but you repeatedly treat it as though it does:

e.g.:

```
head = new Node<Type>(other.head->info);
```

and:

```
node->next = new Node<Type>(current->info);
```

The only single parameter constructors are the implementation defined copy and move constructors which will take `Node<Type>` and not `Type` (or strictly some form of reference to `Node<Type>`).